# Beginner question in Java: How do I create a method that takes multiple values and returns them to main?

Tags: java, methods

I'm learning Java (I don't really get methods tbh.), and my complicated plan is driving me nuts so I'd really appreciate if one of you superior coders could help me with this or let me know that this sucks or doesn't work. **Please also read the text at the end or you might waste your time.** :-D

I want the following: The **main method** and it's class include a couple of arrays:

```
String AnimalList[] = { "frog", "dog", "rabbit", "donkey", "cow", "chicken" };
String HumanList[] = { "man", "woman", "child", "grandpa", "grandma", "baby" };
```

...3 Animals:

```
String Animal1; String Animal2; String Animal3;
```

...and 3 Humans:

```
String Human1; String Human2; String Human3;
```

I want to create a **Generator method**, that randomly picks 3 of the array entries, compares them with the other picks to avoid duplication and than sends them back to main. Something like:

```
for 
(Animal1 = AnimalList[(byte)(Math.random()*AnimalList.length), 
Animal2 = AnimalList[(byte)(Math.random()*AnimalList.length), 
Animal3 = AnimalList[(byte)(Math.random()*AnimalList.length)]; 
Animal1.equals(Animal2) || Animal1.equals(Animal3) || Animal2.equals(Animal3) ;
Animal2 = AnimalList[(byte)(Math.random()*AnimalList.length), 
Animal3 = AnimalList[(byte)(Math.random()*AnimalList.length)] );
```

I want the "Animal1" and "AnimalList" be **automatically** picked whenever I use this method on Strings to work for any other list aswell so that I can **basically send Humans1, Human2 and Humans3 and HumansList into the Generator method and get their values defined in main** just like it worked for Animal1-3 and the AnimalList. I need these operations quite often in my project.
This would save me a lot of space in my code and it looks better sorted. In case one of you shows me how to do this or that this plan just doesn't work... THANK YOU!!! 
*(Sorry if there are things messed up in my code.)*

Comment: I didn't undestand what you want as output. Do you just want your 3 animals and your 3 humans to be set in 1 animal (3 times) and 1 human (also 3 times) without repeating and randomly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes. I only want to use these variables in main without having to repeat the code. So after human1 and human2 are defined in Generator, they shall be saved in main and show up if i mention them in println like Animal1; as "frog". There are many arrays in my project and it's become way too long already.

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Convention: variable names always start with lowercase

Comment: Thanks so much! This is amazing!  I might finally understand this. Your the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that fields traditionally start with lowercase letters.

To help with your confusion about methods, I've written a method that chooses a random element of an array. In the main method I've used this method to choose a random animal and a random human. Once assigned, these fields can be reused in `main` and in other methods in the class.

I'm leaving the part about choosing three of each up to you; hopefully this will get you started. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
public class HumansAndAnimals
{
  static String animalList[] = { "frog", "dog", "rabbit", "donkey", "cow", "chicken" };
  static String humanList[] = { "man", "woman", "child", "grandpa", "grandma", "baby" }; 

  static String animal1; static String animal2; static String animal3;

  static String human1; static String human2; static String human3;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    animal1 = chooseFromArray(animalList);
    System.out.println("First animal: " + animal1);

    human1 = chooseFromArray(humanList);
    System.out.println("First human: " + human1);
  }

  private static String chooseFromArray(String[] arr) {
    return arr[(byte)(Math.random()*arr.length)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work. It says:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field animal1
 AnimalList cannot be resolved to a variable
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field animal1
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field human1
 HumanList cannot be resolved to a variable
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field human1

 at HumansAndAnimals.main(HumansAndAnimals.java:12)

Comment: Ah you're right (to tell the truth static things confuse me). I've made an edit to fix this by making the `animal` and `human` fields static. I've also fixed a problem with using the wrong case on the array references.

Answer (score 0):

You go do the following:

- Keep the list with all animals somewhere. You should consider using a `List` instead of an array.
- Make a copy of the full list, for instance by using `copy = new ArrayList<>(fullList)`.
- Pick a random index using `Random.nextInt(copy.size())`. Put it in a fresh list where you store the three animals. Remove the element from the copy, so it cannot be picked again.
- Repeat these steps two times and return your fresh list with three animals.